# Active Record Query - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a method called `Visit` and it basically adds on the the visit counter on `Subscriber`. This method gets triggered when a `Subscriber` enters their phone_number in a form. I simply want to make a active record query that will look something like this `Susbcriber.find_by(params[id]).last.visit`(this doesn't work BTW). Hopefully you get what I'm trying to do there, basically call the person that checked in last with their phone number. I'll show my code for clarity.

CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
 def search
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
 end

 def visit
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:phone_number])
  if @subscriber
   @subscriber.visit ||= 0
   @subscriber.visit += 1
   @subscriber.save
   flash[:notice] = flash[:notice] = "Thank You #{@subscriber.first_name}. You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
  redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
 else
  render "search"
 end
end
```

There you can see the method that gets triggered when a Subscriber inputs their phone number. I simply want to call that person in the console.

CONTROLLER METHOD THAT IS NOT WORKING CURRENTLY:

```
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:subscriber_id])
    @comment = @subscriber.comments.build(comments_params)
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
    redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

This is the method that needs the new query to find the Subscriber that just entered their phone number.

Let me know if you need more info? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm editing my answer to be more inclusive based on the comments.  It seems like you've got a number of issues going on here and maybe you need to step back and rebuild this step by step.  Consider test driving it and/or at least verify that you're getting what you expect using a debugging tool as you go along (byebug, pry, or even just judicious use of 'puts' and 'inspect').

The find_by method requires that you specify the attribute that you're trying to use to find the row by, as well as the value of the attribute

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number])
```

If you are using the model's primary key, just use find:

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
```

If you're calling a controller action, params should always be present.  Try inspecting the params before moving on with any of the rest of the code.  Make sure that you're getting what you expect.  If not, evaluate your view code.

Comment: I like what you're thinking but I'm getting the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object`?

Comment: That's telling you that there is no 'params' variable in your method.  You're getting this in your controller?  If so, there's something wrong with how you're defining and/or calling your controller.  What controller action is this in, visit or create?  And, how are you calling that action?  What does your view code look like that makes the form submission?

Comment: Also, what version of Rails is this on?  If it's Rails 4+, you should be using strong parameters.

Comment: `Subscriber.find(params[:id])` returns an object, not collection

Comment: @RSB - true.  I was just modifying the original code (thus the 'last').  I'll edit my answer.  My point was that he was using find_by incorrectly, which is still true.  I think the vote down is a little harsh.

Comment: Also, its `params[:id]` and not `params[id]`

Comment: @hightempo, first and foremost. I'm pretty new to rails so I'm not very clear on what I'm trying to do myself... All I know is that I need a way to find the person who last used that method. I'm really struggling to find a better way to say it. But, yes the visit is what I'm calling and I'll post the view code shortly

Comment: No worries.  If you can clarify I am sure I (or someone else) can help you.